Validate TimestampResponse file with signed CADES file
I have two files: a file signed CADES (p7m), and a file with detached timestamp of signed file (tsr).
I want to validate tsr with p7m to make sure the timestamp is relative to the p7m file.
I used java (java11) and bouncycastle (1.56) to validate.
From tsd I get MessageImprintDigest:
byte[] byteTsr = org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils.readFileToByteArray(new File(fileTsr));
org.bouncycastle.tsp.TimeStampResponse response = new TimeStampResponse(byteTsr);
org.bouncycastle.tsp.TimeStampToken tstoken = response.getTimeStampToken();
TimeStampTokenInfo tstInfo = tstoken.getTimeStampInfo();
String responseMessageDigest = Base64.encode(tstInfo.getMessageImprintDigest());

From p7m I get MessageImprintDigest:
TimeStampRequest request = null;
try(FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(new File(filep7m))){
    CMSSignedData signedData = new CMSSignedData(fis);
    SignerInformationStore signers = signedData.getSignerInfos();
    SignerInformation si = (SignerInformation)signers.getSigners().iterator().next();            
    Security.addProvider(new BouncyCastleProvider());
                
    TimeStampRequestGenerator generator = new TimeStampRequestGenerator();
    request = generator.generate(TSPAlgorithms.SHA256, signDigest);
}
String requestMessageDigest = Base64.encode(request.getMessageImprintDigest());

But responseMessageDigest is different from requestMessageDigest.
Why?
If I verify p7m and tsr with an external tool, there is correct matching and the validation is successfull.
Who can help me?
I expected MessageImprintDigest from TimestampResponse is equal to MessageImprintDiget of TimestampRequest.
Actually it's not like that.

I don't know the answer to your question, but as a matter of principle, I wouldn't compare Base64-encoded strings. There could be variations that are unimportant to the plaintext binary content, but exhibiting differences in the actual encoded string values. Also, you can drop reliance on some 3rd party APIs. e.g. you can use Files.readAllBytes and use java.util.Base64
